# How to save selected text from webview which can be uniquely identify next time

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-webview, jsoup

I have a task in which i have to save selected text from the Webview in a way by which i can uniquely identify that when i open that page again in Webview.

1. I have already tried to get selected text from Webview which is easy. I have used below method for retrieve selected text from webview

   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

   ```
           browser.evaluateJavascript("(function(){return window.getSelection().toString()})()",
                   new ValueCallback<String>() {
                       @Override
                       public void onReceiveValue(String value) {
                           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ((value.length() > 0) ? "Selected Text:\n" + value : "Please select text"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       }
                   });
       }
   ```

But now i am trying to retrieve tag/id of that element using which, i think, i can use to uniquely identify the selected element.

- I searched the [webView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) document for the supported methods to achieve
  this, but did not find any specific API.
- I search jsoup library to parse the HTML, and tried finding the text but that approach does not cover most of the cases (I know.. it's bad!!)
- I tried the JSoup library, but when I searched it, the JSoup APIs also does not have any such API/functionality to work with selected text.

I don't have very much knowledge of JS so please let me know if you have better suggestion.

3. I found [rangy](https://github.com/timdown/rangy) a JS library. But I am now getting how to integrate it with my code. 
   I've tried the following

   webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/javascript/rengy", url, "text/html", "utf-8", "");

   - loading the js assets for Rangy so that I could call it's functions
   - Trying to initialize the Rangy library (rangy.init), but that also does not seem to work. (I am definitely missing something simple, but unable to figure out yet)

Can I use any other JS library in the same way? Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: `which can be uniquely identify next time`. It is unclear to me what you want to identify the next time.

Comment: `which, i think, i can use to uniquely identify the selected element. ` Will you have more selections for one webpage?

Comment: I want to select one at a time but 2 things are there.
1. selected text can be large and may be have more then one parent tag.
2. User can do it multiple times with one page .